# I installed ubuntu after the windows 10 and lost windows partitions I saw in "disks" there are two partitions one FAT and other one is ext4

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

so please tell me whether the windows data is wiped out or still it is accessible

Comment: Ubuntu has almost definitely overwritten Windows. You can use a file recovery program to try to get some of the Windows files back, but I think you're out of luck. https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/testdisk/

Answer (score 0):

From Windows 7 onwards Microsoft does not allow other operating systems to be put along side it.
So yes you have lost Windows.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, many users have Ubuntu & Windows on the same hard drive and dual boot whether BIOS/MBR or UEFI/gpt. Windows does make it a bit more difficult but easy to reinstall boot loaders and repair systems if needed.